# I wanted to get data from server using flask and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, server

So I tried javascript below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mtime").bind("click", function (e) {
        $.getJSON('/test', function(data){
            if(data.result==15){
                alert("success!");
            }else{
                alert("fail....");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And made route using flask like this

```
@app.route('/test',methods=[GET,POST])
def test():
    return jsonify(result=15)
```

But when I clicked the 'mtime' , alert method did not work.
And got this message from cmd window

```
"GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 -"
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: `@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`?

Answer (score 0):

As PJ Santoro wrote there are the quotation marks missing around GET and POST. However you don't need to add the methods explicitly as you only make a `GET` request which is the default.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return jsonify(result=15)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Also it's better practice if you use `url_for` in your HTML file to generate the url for your endpoint. This way you can be sure the url changes when you decide to change your subdomain or use a Blueprint.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#mtime").bind("click", function (e) {
    $.getJSON({{ url_for('test') }}, function(data){
        if(data.result==15){
            alert("success!");
        }else{
            alert("fail....");
        }
    });
  });
});
```